# Unable to zoom in the bus route map

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

i have a bus route map as an image.
using the zoom controller the image is zooming out but not zooming in
please look at my code and let me know the change to be done make it working..
i am developing my app on Gingerbread i.e API 10

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

 public class Busmaps extends Activity {

ImageView img;
ZoomControls zoom;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.busmaps);

    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewmaps1);
    zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);

    zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w + 50, h + 50);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        img.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
  });

      zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int w = img.getWidth();
        int h = img.getHeight();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(w - 50, h - 50);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        img.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
  });
  }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bus_map_zoom, menu);
    return true;
  }
  }
```

my xml says for bus route image:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewmaps1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/map" />

  <ZoomControls
    android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

how should i make my zoom control working for both Zoom in and Zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Busmap extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.busmaps);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewmaps1);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                            mode = DRAG;
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                            mode = NONE;
                                            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                            oldDist = spacing(event);
                                            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                            if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                midPoint(mid, event);
                                                mode = ZOOM;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                            }
                                            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                            if (mode == DRAG) 
                                            { 
                                                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                            } 
                                            else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                            { 
                                                // pinch zooming
                                                float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                {
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                // zoom out
                                                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}



private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}



private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your Zoom in and ZoomOut listener with the following:

```
zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float x = img.getScaleX();
        float y = img.getScaleY();

        img.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
        img.setScaleY((float) (y+1));
    }
});

    zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        float x = img.getScaleX();
        float y = img.getScaleY();

        img.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
        img.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
    }
});
}
```

Alternate option is to load the image in the Web view which has build in zoom controller.

As follows:

```
 String page = "<html><body><center><img src=\""+path to your image+"\"/></center></body></html>";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake",page, "text/html", "UTF-8","");
```

If you dont want to use the build in web view zoom controller then you can just place your own buttons and apply zoom in and zoom out on web view as follows:

```
webView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);
```

Comment: getScaleX/Y() was included from Honeycomb i.e API 12
i am developing my app on Gingerbread i.e API 10

can u please help me with some other solution

Comment: please check i have edited my answer
 See if it works for you

Comment: my code is working i just want know that why it just zooms once and does not zoom further...
do i need to define something border/pixel or m i missing something...

i would request you to please review my code again and let me know

Comment: is there anything like screen size or the image size that is to be defined due to which i am unable to zoom further...